# Switch divs every 10secs using jquery?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, setinterval

I have two div's setup that when clicked on a link switch from blue to orange. The sit in the same place and just give the impression of swapping from one colour to the other. This is my jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $(".dab").click(function(){
        $("#pf-orange-area").show();
        $("#pf-blue-area").hide();
    });
    $(".pfs").click(function(){
        $("#pf-orange-area").hide();
        $("#pf-blue-area").show();
    });
});
```

How I keep that functionality but also make them switch every 10 secs automatically?

Comment: why two `jQuery(document).ready(function( $ )`

Comment: @captain Inexperience! I'll merge them into one.

Comment: A great idea would be to put the actual color switching into a function and then simply call that function in a `setTimeout` and in the click handler.

Comment: They can be nested together, no need to check if the document is ready twice.  Not WRONG as such, just no need for it.

Comment: You are probably looking for Javascript's `setTimeout`, you don't need jQuery for this, I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setTimeout

Comment: `setInterval` might be more appropriate, as it is to change *every* 10secs

Comment: @msturdy you are correct, my bad.

Comment: I saw my answer made it in late, but figured you might look at it anyway. I gave you a lot of comments and tried to fully explain what's going on so you can see just how easy this operation can be and how to "understand"  what you're doing. Good luck and welcome to SO! Enjoy jQuery! It's tons of fun!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var $or = $("#pf-orange-area"),
        $bl = $("#pf-blue-area"),
        changeColor;

    $(".dab").click(function(){
        $or.show();
        $bl.hide();
    });

    $(".pfs").click(function(){
        $or.hide();
        $bl.show();
    });

    changeColor = function() {
        $or.toggle();
        $bl.toggle();
    };

    setInterval(changeColor, 10000);
});
```

Thus, one of his colored elements must come now hidden and the other displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Use **`setInterval()`** in your code.  Something like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var toggle = function () {
        $("#pf-orange-area, #pf-blue-area").toggle();
    }
    var anim = setInterval(toggle, 1000);
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        clearInterval(anim);
    });
});
```

To pause/stop animation then

```
clearInterval(anim);
```

Check this [**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/S8cGZ/2/)

Comment: @Rob I'm trying to show a code sample.  So you can easily understand.

Answer (score 2):

setInterval should work here.

Consider:

```
window.setInterval(yourfunction, 10000); //10000 = 10 sec

function yourfunction() { alert('test'); } //whatever you want it to do, test is purely for demonstration purposes
```

Comment: A better practice is to define the functions before are being used. Code-Redability-sake

Comment: That's true.  I wasn't thinking about readability at the time of answering!  You should see some of my code, far from readable haha.

Answer (score 1):

```
var b = true;

setInterval(function() {
   $( b ? '.dab' : '.pfs').trigger('click');
   b = ! b;
}, 10000);
```

Comment: or simply `.click();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var i = 0,
handle = setInterval(function(){


    if(i%2 === 0){ //every other time (0,2,4 etc)

        $("#pf-orange-area").show();
        $("#pf-blue-area").hide();

    }else{ // every 'odd' time (1,2,3)

        $("#pf-orange-area").hide();
        $("#pf-blue-area").show();

    }    

    i++; 
},10000);

//to stop it:
//clearInterval(handle);
```

Depending on the initial visibility state, you might want to switch the if and else bodies.

Comment: Instead of unnecessary repeating code, why not just e.g: `$(".dab").click();` ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Instead of triggering a click, both cases should be added to a function, referenced as a click handler callback and triggered in the interval. Something I prefer over triggering an event. But I figured he might do something himself :)

Answer (score 0):

As others said you can use setInterval. but for implementation I suggest this:

```
function toggleAreas() {
    $("#pf-blue-area, #pf-orange-area").toggle();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(toggleAreas, 10000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I saw you finally selected an answer, but figured i'd throw my two cents on in since I made this example with a long explanation. I hope this helps a bit in your understanding.

The first example has a variable for a timer, so that your 10 seconds can be reset everytime there is a change. This way, clicking on the elements having your class names also reset the timer.

> **Side Note:** In the following examples I use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). If you're using a jQuery prior to 1.7, you can simply replace [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

## Example

```
var tmrShowHide;  //  this variable will act as out timer for keeping up with time changes
    //    if you don't want to reset the 10 seconds everytime there is a change, 
    //    then please see exmple 2
function divShowHide() {  //  this will be the method used to change the colors and reset the timer
    clearTimeout(tmrShowHide);    //    clears previous timer so 10 seconds is reset

    //  the .toggle method will simply toggle the visible state (display in css) of the element it's called upon
    //  so if we start with one hidden and one visible, then this is all that is needed to make the change!
    //  also note that i'm calling both elements at once, as they'll both undergo the "toggle" change
    $('#pf-blue-area, #pf-orange-area').toggle();

    tmrShowHide = setTimeout(divShowHide, 10000);    //    resets timer to 10 seconds
}

$(function() {  //  Same as $(document).ready(function() { // just shorter!
    //  the following establiches our click event on the 2 class types
    $(document).on('click', '.dab, .pfs', divShowHide);
    //  this will begin the timer and give us a variable that can be cleared as needed
    tmrShowHide = setTimeout(divShowHide, 10000);
})
```

So without comments its as simple as:

```
var tmrShowHide;
function divShowHide() {
    clearTimeout(tmrShowHide);
    $('#pf-blue-area, #pf-orange-area').toggle();
    tmrShowHide = setTimeout(divShowHide, 10000);
}

$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.dab, .pfs', divShowHide);
    tmrShowHide = setTimeout(divShowHide, 10000);
})
```

---

---

---

This next example is much shorter in that it doesn't reset the timer, thus, clicking on a class element to make the change will not stop it from changing every 10 seconds.

## Example 2

```
function divShowHide(e) {  //  this will be the method used to change the colors
    //  the .toggle method will simply toggle the visible state (display in css) of the element it's called upon
    //  so if we start with one hidden and one visible, then this is all that is needed to make the change!
    //  also note that i'm calling both elements at once, as they'll both undergo the "toggle" change
    $('#pf-blue-area, #pf-orange-area').toggle();
}

$(function() {  //  Same as $(document).ready(function() { // just shorter!
    //  the following establishes our click event on the 2 class types
    $(document).on('click', '.dab, .pfs', divShowHide);
    //  this will begin the unstoppable 10 second timer
    setInterval(divShowHide, 10000);
})
```

So without comments its as simple as:

```
function divShowHide(e) {  $('#pf-blue-area, #pf-orange-area').toggle();  }

$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.dab, .pfs', divShowHide);
    setInterval(divShowHide, 10000);
})
```

#### The Blinker! (<sub>just for fun</sub>)